# Как правильно использовать хук useDispatch react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Часть кода **компонента**:

```
const TopicsScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const topics = useSelector(selectTopics, shallowEqual)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTopics())
  }, [])
```

Код **селектора**

```
export const selectTopics = (state) => {
  console.log('inside')
  return state.topicsData.topics
}
```

Меня мучают следующие вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я использую хук `useDispatch`? Все работает, но консоль выводит фразу 'inside' 4 раза вместо двух, хотя я вроде пользуюсь функцией `shallowEqual`. Когда компонент был написан с помощью функции connect 'inside' выводилось всего два раза как и предполагается. Как оптимизировать код и нужно ли это?
2. Читал что `useEffect` лучше не использовать с пустым аргументом в скобках, и код у меня не лучшее решение. Как исправить и что поместить внутрь?
3. Также насчет `useEffect`. Нужно ли убирать за этим хуком и если да то как?

---

Не знаю насколько это важно, но я использую библиотеку redux-thunk, и функция `getTopics` - асинхронный запрос к БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. нормально Вы используете `useDispatch`. по-другому его никак и не использовать. а если `shallowEqual` не помогает, то придется использовать **Reselect** или подобную ему чепуху для мемоизации (более подробно [на офф документации](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates)). Вы, кстати, можете сами написать функцию `shallowEqual`, правда придется писать её для каждого селектора.
2. использовать `useEffect` с пустыми зависимостями (аргументами) - нормально, потому что как Вы иначе будет использовать методы жизненного цикла в функциональных компонентах?
3. если под *убирать* Вы имели в виду задачу цикла `componentWillUnmount`, то, конечно, да.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но вот с аргументами useEffect вопросы по прежнему остались. https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/445276/ вот в этой статье говорится, что когда используются пустые зависимости мы не полностью честны с вызовом. Мне скорее интересно, как поступить именно в этой ситуации. У меня есть данные которые надо загрузить и отрендерить, как мне добавить зависимость в useeffect?

Comment: @some1, если Вы в `useEffect` загружаете какие-то данные (через `fetch`), то их нужно записывать в `state`. соответственно, хук `useEffect` выполнил свою задачу и ему уже не надо еще раз срабатывать. по-этому у него должны быть пустые зависимости (аргументы)

Comment: большое спасибо!